# Reversed indices

Tags: math-mode, positioning, subscripts

How do I type *<sub>1</sub>A* in LaTeX as in the snippet below?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used `newtxtext`, `newtxmath` to obtain the same fonts of your image.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
$A=({}_{1}A, \ldots, {}_{j}A)$
\end{document}
```

There are different alternatives to obtain your example: using, for example,[`tensor`](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tensor/tensor.pdf) package which provides for a little bit of a lower subscripts.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{tensor}
\begin{document}
$A=(\tensor[_1]{A}{}, \ldots, \tensor[_j]{A}{})$
\end{document}
```

Comment: What are the packages `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` here ?

Comment: @user2925716 Simply to correspond to the character of the image.

Comment: Sorry, my English is poor, what do you mean by "correspond to the character of the image" ?

Comment: @user2925716 Also mine: to correspond=to have. If you not put `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`, but you use `amsmath package` you will have the CM fonts (computer modern)